# .net framework CLI standards hosting organization?

Tags: .net, clr, standards

Does anyone know what organization is hosting the .net framework Common Language infrastructure (CLI) standards and where you can I go and read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was originally submitted to ECMA. ECMA has in turn submitted it to ISO.

The CLI specification is [ECMA-335](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). It was later submitted to ISO as [ISO/IEC 23271:2006](http://Standards.ISO.Org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042927_ISO_IEC_23271_2006(E).zip) and [ISO/IEC TR 23272:2006](http://Standards.ISO.Org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042928_ISO_IEC_TR_23272_2006(E).zip). The specification includes the CTS, VES, CIL and the libraries, also specification of the metadata and the debug interchange format.

The other pieces of the .NET puzzle are specified in [ECMA-334](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) aka. [ISO/IEC 23270:2006](http://Standards.ISO.Org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c042926_ISO_IEC_23270_2006(E).zip) for C# and [ECMA-372](http://WWW.ECMA-International.Org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm) for C++/CLI (note: no ISO spec for this one).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ECMA CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Try [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)